# automatically redirect to website home page

Tags: html, flash

Today I got a new task.

in that task i have to make one website intro and have to run with html page. that i know haw to do it. and i have done with this part.

but now i have to do one thing that is. when my intro is completed then page will automatically redirect to website home page.

is it possible then page will be redirect without single click. if yes then how.

Please reply to solve this problem.

Thanking you And Kindly Regards.
          Jeyson

Answer (score 0):

At the end of animation add a keyframe and attach:

In AS2 :    `getURL("home.html");`

In AS3 :    `navigateToURL(new URLRequest("home.html"));`

I found it [here](http://activeden.net/forums/thread/help-how-to-redirect-from-flash-animation/2614).

---

Just to make sure you know errors, you may use: (AS3 Code)

```
var url:String = "home.html";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
try 
  {
   navigateToURL(request, "_self");
  } 
catch (e:Error) 
  {
   trace("Error occurred!");
  }
```

Comment: i use this code but still its not redirecting. can you please explain me more about the same.

Comment: May I know which version of actionscript are you using. And exactly what is the problem you encounter with the above??

Comment: i am using a flash cs3. about the scripting part then i am using a as3. i have to redirect page without click event. like when my intro is finished then that page will redirect to my index page.

Comment: Are you trying the redirect locally? Then perhaps, your flash restrictions might be preventing the redirect. Dump the page in the server & check.